# rails_admin how to display only the current_users associated records

Tags: rails-admin

Using rails_admin let's assume we have 3 users and 10 stores.

The first user has `role == 'root'` and the other 2 users have `role == 'admin'`.

There is a typical rails `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship successfully established between `User` and `Store`.

When any `User` accesses the rails_admin engine `/admin`, I'd like that `User` to be able to access any `Store` that they are associated with or in the case of the `role == 'root'` User, they should be able to access all the Stores.

I'm digging through the rails admin wiki and I'm not really seeing anything that would give me this ability.

I'm thinking there is a customization somewhere that would display only stores that the current_user has as relations (or whatever other conditions I specify).

Any thoughts here?

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 0):

Use cancancan with rails_admin:
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence

Your example going to be resolved with:

```
can :manage, Store do |store|
  store.users.include? current_user
end
```